# bash: exec $var>&1 doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, sh, io-redirection

How can I use variables in the exec command?

If I do the command below, it works:

```
$ exec 3>&1
```

But if I execute the following, it gives me an error:

```
$ var=3; exec $var>&1
bash: exec: 3: not found
```

I would like to save in a variable so it won't be hard coded when I need to use the descriptor 3 latter in the script.

Comment: You'll probably have to `eval exec $var>&1`

Comment: FWIW `var=3` `exec $var>&1` works in `zsh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making the file descriptor configurable, let `bash` itself allocate an unused file descriptor for you.

```
exec {var}>&1
```

You can then use `$var` later in other redirections.

```
printf '%s' "Some message" >&$var
```